# Perfect to me vs Perfect for me

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What is the difference between "Perfect to me" vs "Perfect for me"?
Please explain it to me

Comment: Please provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like some examples sentences and ideally any research you have done regarding the prepositions _to_ and _for_.

Answer (score 5):

When describing something that is exactly right for me or for my personal use, I would say "perfect for me".

> This shirt fits me well and it's my style - it's **perfect for me**.
>
> I don't need to drink a lot to have a good time, one beer is **perfect for me**.

If it's my opinion that something is perfect, then I would say it looks "perfect to me".

> I don't know why the judge gave the diver an 8 out of 10, the dive looked **perfect to me**.

Answer (score 4):

"Perfect to me" expresses your opinion of perfection in the object.

> That painting looks perfect to me.  Don't change a thing.

"Perfect for me" expresses ideal suitability of the object for your use.

> That painting is perfect for me.  I'm going to hang it in my dressing room.

Comment: The first example is not about `perfect to me`, it is about `looks to me`. Can you please think of another example without `looks` or of two examples that both have `looks` but differ in `to/for` part?

Comment: @chumakoff The examples are 100% correct.  No change necessary.  That 'looks' and 'is' are different verbs makes no difference.

Comment: Do you mean that in your first example if I replace `looks` with `is` it will still be a correct answer?

Comment: @chumakoff Makes no difference with respect to OP's question.  You can change the second to 'looks' as well with no difference.